# Getting new PHP version in WAMP to load

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, php, wamp

I'm downgrading my WAMP from 5.5.12 to 5.3.10, I added exported php-5.3.10-Win32-VC9-x86.zip to C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\

I've added the necessary php5apache2_4.dll into the php5.3.10 folder and also copied over the php.ini, phpForApache.ini, and the wampserver.conf from 5.5.12 and then changed any references from 5.5.12 to 5.3.10 in each of those three files.

From what I've read all I should need to do is restart WAMP or close and open WAMP to see the new PHP version show up when I left click on WAMP > PHP > Version but I still only see the old version in there.

Was WAMP suppose to automatically pick up the new version, it seems like something else needs to be configured but I can't figure out what it is.

Also when adding the new php5apache2_4.dll there's notes to add the following to my httpd.conf file but that only prevents WAMP from properly loading even after removing the references to the original php5apache2_4.dll

```
 LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/php5apache2_4.dll"
 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

 # configure the path to php.ini
 PHPIniDir "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/"
```

But besides that my main issue is getting the new PHP version to show up in the list of PHP versions installed on the WAMP menu bar so that I can click on the new version to switch over to it.

I have read a couple guides for manually adding different PHP versions and they all seem to say just plop in the new PHP folder, modify the three files mentioned in my second paragraph, restart WAMP and the new PHP option should automatically show up.

I've found in the wampmanager.ini where I can manually modify the PHP listings but I didn't know if this was the correct way to add your new PHP version to your PHP version list in WAMP.

Also each PHP folder has it's own php.ini and a phpForApache.ini file; however, there's another php.ini file in bin\apache\apache2.4.9.

There's the extension_dir that points to the php folder extension locations and a zend_extension which also points to the current version of zend_ext both files are located in their respective PHP version folders.

Was this something I would need to manually comment out and uncomment when switching between versions? Could I leave both uncommented? (I would imagine not) But I don't see how WAMP could automatically know whether to comment or uncomment each of these extension references.

Same goes for the apache2.4.0\conf\httpd.conf file in regards to LoadModule php5_module for each php version, could I leave both uncommented or was this something I had to manually comment and uncomment manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have most of this process right, but here are a few bit I can see that are causing problems.

Copying the php.ini phpForApache.ini etc files from a php5.5 to a php5.3 is going to cause problems. There where many changes between these 2 versions. Compare the 2 by all means but start from a vanilla php5.3 php.ini and manually make the filename changes rather than just doing a copy.

Dont manually change the httpd.conf file like you did, once WAMPServer spots the 2 versions of PHP, when you do the switch WAMPServer will do all the necessary mods itself, thats what the switch process does. You probably confused it a bit by doing it manually

So chnage this

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

back to use the 5.5 php

Also, dont add this line to httpd.conf, the switch process does not look for this parameter and therefore it will naff the switching process. Leave it

```
PHPIniDir "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/"
```

leave it commented out